# Does microwaves (or other types of wave) be able to disrupt radar signals?

Tags: physics, military, radiation, stealth

The idea is that this next generation fighter jet would have some microwave or electromagnetic emitters to disrupt the travel path of the waves radars emits and "disappear" from the map, but I don't know how feasible it would be.

For example, to make any difference at all, I would need such enormous amount of energy that the pilot and the electronic systems would just fry up.

And I just suggested microwaves because it is the only type of wave I know that fries up any time of electronic object (besides electromagnetism).

But hey, if this was even possible, governments would already apply this to their aircraft.

Comment: it would also be far easier to detect the jet, just use a passive receiver to pinpoint the very "loud" transmitter.

Comment: I see a few downvotes and a close vote and no explanations as to why.  I know that this question makes some false assumptions about technology, but false assumptions are not necessarily a sign of a bad question.  A question that can only be answered with a Frame Challenge should be treated as fine as long as it does not violate other WB.SE criteria for asking questions.

Comment: Radio waves are themselves inserted between other kinds of wave. The problem here is that a Google search on how [radars](https://www.explainthatstuff.com/radar.html) and microwaves work already answers the question to quite an extent. From the damage potential of the microwaves: it causes the metals to start heating up and thus the electronics suffer problems related to overheating and arcing between metallic components; to searching how [stealth planes](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stealth_aircraft) use the very method proposed here, just not necessarily with microwaves.

Comment: You are describing Jammers and Spoofers: flooding radar receivers with either broadband noise or carefully shaped pulses so the radar set can't detect its own returning radar pulse to compute Range and Direction with accuracy.  Jammers try to hide everything and spoofers try to shift the position or generate multiple returns so there look to be many more contacts to the radar set.  Spoofers need to operate on the frequency range of the radar system and Jammers dump out noise centered around the radar's fundamental frequency

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is called radar jamming, and it is a very real technology that has existed since WWII.  Jamming does not exactly make a fighter disappear from enemy radars. Instead, you fill the enemy radar with a giant false positive such that the entire sky appears full of possible targets.  Radar only works if you can key in on the return signal, but by broadcasting random noise over the return signal, you can make any real returns be lost in the staic.  If you know the exact frequency of a radar you are trying to jam, then your jamming emitter does not need significantly more power than the radar being used.  When the jamming radar does not know the frequency of the enemy, you require a much more powerful emitter than your target to broadcast static across all probable frequencies at once.

As AlexP pointed out in comments, most modern aircraft can randomise or change their frequencies making it very difficult for an aircraft to hold the equipment necessary to jam another craft of equivalent size, but there are also more technologies today that allow for effective wide-frequency jamming.  One is to use large ground based jamming stations or specialized aircraft like the E-767 to jam on all frequencies using emitters that are MUCH more powerful than would fit on most military craft.  Another  even more modern method is using directional jamming.  Directional jamming relies on seeing your enemy before they see you, but once you know where they are you can use a directional emitter with a wide frequency to jam a specific target's radar, without needing a more powerful emitter than they have because they still need to scan a large area to find you whereas you can keep your focus narrow.

JohnO brought up in comments the issue of becoming a "big red bullseye", but this is only a problem in certain contexts. Even having your jammer's position known can still be a huge tactical advantage as long as your enemies are blind to your other activities.

[image]

Furthermore, in the case of narrow angle directional jamming, you can hit a receiver with so much static that you not only fill their system with noise, but you fill it passed the upper gamut of their receiver.  In this case, it's like shining a flashlight in someone's eyes, and the target becomes unable to differentiate anything from the background rendering it unable to tell where the jamming signal is coming from with any precision.

One last caveat to remember about modern aerial warfare, is that electronic countermeasures are not just 1 technology that always works, but it's about layering as many countermeasures as you can to survive.  Jamming is just 1 tool meant to be used in addition to stealth paint, aircraft geometry, IR restricting propulsion systems, flares, chaff, lasers, plasma shields, etc. Every countermeasure exists because it does something that other countermeasures don't do so don't assume that just because you are jamming someone that you are completely safe from them.  You never know what they have thought up to overcome your countermeasure.

Comment: It should be noted that "jamming" is a good way to paint a big red bullseye on your backside with flashing lights saying "drop bombs here".

Comment: @JohnO See revisions.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, radar uses microwaves and doesn't fry itself up, nor fries any airplane which is tracked. Else nobody would fly.

Second, electromagnetic waves do not disrupt the travel path of other electromagnetic waves. Have you ever seen the lamp of your kitchen disturbing the path of the sun beam seeping through the shutter or vice versa?

What one could in principle do is send back a signal with equal power and frequency and just opposite phase with respect to the incoming radar wave, so that the the resulting electromagnetic signal would be flat.

In practice it is sufficient for the emitter to randomly change the pulse duration/frequency or to use multiple listening stations to have any airplane using this countermeasure shout its presence in the sky.

Comment: i mean you can flood signals by having light "covering" up a range of frequencies. it just needs a very very powerful tool to cover that big of a range for it to really cause a problem.